# pop() empty deque() in logic

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to be able to validate parenthesis so they enclose and ignore any type of characters. As long as there is the valid use of enclosure of strings with parenthesis then `True` else `False.

I am still new to python so I'm not sure how to properly create an if statement for this certain condition. I am trying to create an fi statement such that when I `.pop()` an empty `deque()` I will be able to `return False` instead of receiving the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

Perhaps there is another better method around solving this problem. If so I would be glad to see how someone else would solve it

For example:

```
a = 'sdf(sadf(sdf)sdf)sdfsd0sdf)sdf(sdf0)' # false 
b = 'dsf))))(((((dsfsdf' # false
c = '()()()()'  # true
d = '((((asd(asd)asd)()()asd))'   # true
```

my code:

```
# any letter is ignored
# jsut make sure that the parenthesis are equal

from collections import *

def str_valid(stringy):
    param_stack = deque()
    for n in stringy:
        if n ==')':
            param_stack.pop()
        if n == '(':
            param_stack.append('(')
    if param_stack == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False 

a = 'sdf(sadf(sdf)sdf)sdfsd0sdf)sdf(sdf0)' # false 
b = 'dsf))))(((((dsfsdf' # false
c = '()()()()'  # true
d = '((((asd(asd)asd)()()asd))'   # true

print str_valid(a)

print str_valid(b)

print str_valid(c)

print str_valid(d)
```

Comment: Why are you using a `deque` for this when a simple integer counter would do just as well? Start it off at 0, increment when you see `(`, decrement when you see `)`, then `return not paren_count` at the end.

Comment: because if you see a `)` in the beginning, nothing will be enclosed properly because enclosures starting with `)` won't work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you need to fail as soon as you go below zero. But you still don't need a container when all you're really interested in is its length. That's like counting to 100 by writing 100 tally marks on the wall.

Comment: @Liondancer, the count starts at 0.  You see `)` at the beginning, see the counter is already 0, so return `False` right away.  If think carefully about your code, you'll see then `len(param_stack)` is exactly the counter he's talking about.  It's just that you're spelling "add 1" as `.append()`, and "subtract 1" as `.pop()` ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters I understand your logic. I just though for fun that I would use a stack for solve this problem. Thank you for both your inputs! much appreciated! =D

Comment: same goes for you @kindall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pop() an empty deque without problems:

```
from collections import deque

d = deque()
try:
    d.pop()
except IndexError:
    pass  # do whatever you want in the case that there is nothing there
    return False # is this what you want?
else:
    pass  # do whatever you want in the case that there is something there
```

Just a warning in case you don't know: keep the amount of code inside any of try/except/else/finally as short and focused as possible. It's easy to end up with errors popping up inside error handlers and leading to surprises.

If that's not what you need, please clarify what in your code is not working.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want an if statement to check if the deque is empty before pop(), you can use

```
if n ==')':
    if param_stack:
        param_stack.pop()
    else:
        return false
...
```

if param_stack will implicitly convert it to a boolean which return true if it contains some elements and false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note:  first, the only methods of `deque` you're using are `append()` and `pop`.  So it's more natural to use an ordinary Python list.  A deque isn't more efficient than a list unless you need to put things on, or take things off, "the left end".

Second, you already know how to test for an empty deque!  You did that here:

```
if param_stack == []:
```

Now that's a little odd, because you're comparing a deque to a list, but it works.  With a little more experience, you'll write that as:

```
if len(param_stack) == 0:
```

and with more experience still, you may use:

```
if not param_stack:
```

(an empty container generally behaves like False in truth-y contexts).

But however you write it, rather than introduce `try/except` blocks, it's easier and clearer to do something like:

```
    if n ==')':
        if param_stack:  # i.e., if it's not empty
            param_stack.pop()
        else:   # it's empty
            return False
```

Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Simply catch the error and return `False`:

```
for n in stringy:
    if n ==')':
        try:
            param_stack.pop()
        except IndexError:
            return False
```

Comment: i tried this and it seems to work. However, i think for some reason, due to my logic, none of the '(' are appending to the list =/

Answer (score 1):

Use try, except to catch the IndexError exception and then return False

```
try:
    param_stack.pop()
except IndexError:
# catch your IndexError exception and do what you want
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

As other people already mentioned you don't really need a queue, a simple counter is enough:

```
def str_valid(txt):
  ctr = 0
  for n in txt:
    if n == '(':
      ctr = ctr + 1
    if n == ')':
      ctr = ctr - 1      
    if ctr < 0:
      return False
  return ctr == 0
```

Or shorter:

```
def str_valid(txt):
  ctr = 0
  for n in txt:
    ctr = ctr + (n == '(') - (n == ')')
    if ctr < 0:
      return False
  return ctr == 0
```

Or a "hacky" one-liner :)

```
def str_valid(txt):
  return not reduce(lambda t, c: t if t < 0 else t + (c == '(') - (c == ')'), txt, 0)
```